# SharePoint 2010 document library Items indenting issue

Tags: 2010, document-library, css

[image]

I have a SharePoint 2010 portal and made 1 Site collection along with subsites. On each sub site I have different document libraries and each document library has documents uploaded.

The strange thing is that the indenting of document names are different. Please have a look and suggest the solution accordinly so all items are aligned equaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well perhaps this would help others also. I have inserted the following line under  section in my masterpage and viola it worked like a charm :)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshots it looks like you have modified the css for the site which can be a good reason the items are drifting towards the left. Check for some added left padding styles written in the class used in the display of grid based sharepoint library and list views.

Comment: Well I did change the masterpage back to V4 but no change in document library items alignment.

Comment: There is something wrong with the css. You need to use firebug or developer tools in IE and select the padding region and see what class is being applied there ..

Comment: it is working fine on mozilla firefox and chrome..it is acting strange on IE..i am currently using IE9

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this a few times.

I usually just change `.ms-vb-icon` from `width: 0.01%;` to `width: 0.1%;` and that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created SPView for each Library to show items OOTB. then it may be possibility that you are showing Name (for use in forms), Name (linked to document),Name (linked to document with edit menu) etc.

So you may be modified some css to show Name with proper indent. but whatever library is showing wrong indent in that library you may choose wrong Name field to show.

It may be possibility. May be it can help.

Answer (score 0):

My take is that we are looking at 2 different web parts, most likely one is a List-View, or Content Query web part, and another could be either created custom or via SharePoint designer. The rendering would be different as the way tables are generated is different.

Could you please check by appending `?contents=1` to your page address and drop us the screenshot which should be a table stating what kind of web parts are deployed on the page?

Comment: Marius all types are XsltListViewWebPart

Comment: ..and no customization performed, or using any separate XSLT added via the Web Part tool part?

Comment: no customization and no seperate XSLT for sure.

Comment: Take one web that looks different than the others, and try adding a new ListView Web part trying to rebuild the same view of content - via Browser UI. If it happens that any of these web parts (even if they are all XsltListViewWebPart) via SPD then the explanation is that.

Comment: Lists on whole web were same. I added list webpart through browser UI. didn't try with SPD though.